# Buffering percentage in CAF v3 Receiver

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

How do I get the buffering load percentage from the Chromecast Receiver CAF v3?

I am developing a custom receiver and would like to be able to show a percentage when buffering a stream, so the user is able to see how close the stream is to starting playback.

I can see that Netflix and others does this with their receiver, so it must be possible, but I cannot find anything about this in the developer documentation.

Comment: Can you please add links to your source code or a minimal viable example of the code you are planning to use and I can work out a solution

Comment: Documentation from Google on how to implement a custom receiver can be found here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/basic
There is also a basic example on that page. I am unsure of what more to post, since I just  want to know how to get a percentage of how much buffering is done before the stream will start playing.

Comment: For what it's worth, Netflix is totally lying about their buffered percentage.  For example, you can see it buffer 25% even with no network connection.  I'm not saying it's impossible... just that things may not be what they seem.